# trying to set properties of objects in array

Tags: objective-c, xcode, sprite-kit

I have 9 objects which are nameds "cajas":

```
//  XYZCajas.h
@interface XYZCajas : SKSpriteNode
@property float distanciaLuna;
@property float grados;
@property BOOL cerca;
@property BOOL astroIsleft;
@property BOOL astroIsRight;


-(XYZCajas*)crearCaja;

@end
```

And they are inside of another object which name is "superCaja", I put them into this "super"object in this method:

```
NSArray *arrayOfObjects = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:caja1, caja2, caja3, caja4, caja5, caja6, caja7, caja8, caja9, nil];
[superCaja setObjects:arrayOfObjects];
```

I'm trying to set a bool of one of those objects "cajas", and the way I'm doing it is like this:

```
int indice = 0;
for(NSNumber* gradosCaja in superCaja.gradosUpdt)
{
    [superCaja.objects[indice]setAstroIsLeft:NO];
    indice ++;
}
```

but it raise an exception:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[XYZCajas setAstroIsLeft:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
```

I know its a noob question but any help would be apreciated and thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Names are case sensitive.

In  `XYZCajas.h` Change this:

```
@property BOOL astroIsleft;
```

to this:

```
@property BOOL astroIsLeft;
```